# jQuery - slideToggle is incomplete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, slidetoggle

I have a strange behavior with slideToggle. Click on the row expands a div under it. but if I double click on the row, while it is expanding down the div, it stops expanding and does not show whole content.

My code is:

```
$("#trHead").delegate("td", "click", function (e) {
     $("#div").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with queing of animation, try

```
$("#trHead").delegate("td", "click", function (e) {
     $("#div").stop(true, true).slideToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: @Zorro can you share the related html as well